# Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies don't support null safety: - package:emoji_picker_2

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:emoji_picker_2

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety

Answer (score 0):

run the following to build your app without null safety or try another packaged.

```
flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```